# How to show multinomial logistic regression formula in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I want to deploy  multinomial logistic regression (or pruned version of this) that is easy to deploy without pickle file

here's the `X`

```
index   2853    1864    2658    11187   2874
0          0       0       1        0      0
1          0       0       0        0      0
2          0       0       0        0      1
```

here's the `y` (categorical)

```
ndex    a.age
0   >50
1   15-20
2   35-50
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
import numpy as np
h = .02
logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1e5)
logreg.fit(X, y)
df = pd.DataFrame(logreg.coef_, columns = X.columns, index = ['15-20' , '35-50' , '>50'])
```

It works